# how can I dim two sets of lights and run a fan by replacing my 3 manual switch

Tags: electrical

Can I get a switch that incorporates 2 dimmers and a manual switch to control a kitchen fan?

Comment: "Shop for me" type questions are considered off topic.

Comment: This is less a shopping and more a "do they exist question", case in point, they don't, at the current time.  I think some allowance for "possibility of" questions needs to be addressed.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean a single gang switch, not a electrical wiring question, yes. From the big box stores in the US at least (Like Lowes and Home Depot) they stock a single gang piece with any combination of up to 4 switches.

[image]

The picture shows an example of one at Lowes, make sure to ask someone or read the box because they also sell models that have a dimmer/switch that runs a single line/appliance; for instance, the image I supplied is actually for running 2 fans.

([Picture source:](http://www.lowes.com/ProductDisplay?partNumber=314805-1571-LSDC163PWV&langId=-1&storeId=10151&productId=3192959&catalogId=10051&cmRelshp=req&rel=nofollow&cId=PDIO1) Lowe's stock image of Pass & Seymour/Legrand 300-Watt White 3-Speed Slide Combination Ceiling Fan and Light Control)

Comment: Partial credit, 3 speed fan slider != dimmer

Answer (score 0):

Not in a single package unless you go to controller based system like X-10 or Z-wave.

I've seen dual dimmers or a dimmer + switch.